# What fields can you call with request.user in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates, request

Sorry for the dumb question but I can't figure it out.

I have a class based view for a form. I like to make some changes if the `request.user` is equal with something.

I used before in some other views `request.user.profile.leader` that gives me a boolean answer. Thats OK.

Now in this class based view I like to use a very similar stuff but with another model like this: `request.user.trust.group` but it gives me nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't customized your user model, then `profile` will appear on it as a reverse descriptor of an one-to-one field on another model ([by way of `related_name` having been set or inferred](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)), i.e. you have something like

```
class Profile(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    leader = models.BooleanField(...)
```

somewhere.

If you expect a `trust` field to be there, then you'd need something similar:

```
class Trust(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="trust")
    group = ...
```

On the other hand, if you do have an [entirely custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), then those attributes could appear directly on it:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, ...)
    trust = models.ForeignKey(Trust, ...)
```